# Background Service for notifications

Tags: java, android, service, webview

I'm working at a Notification provider for my Android application with a WebView that uses a JavaScriptInterface to get info from a remote Javascript file that according to received info from the server, it triggers my application to send a heads up notification.

So, I've added a JavaScript Interface into the onCreate void:

```
OnomeWebContainer.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

And created the WebAppInterface class

```
// Interfacing with Javascript Code
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showTempHumUnavailableNotification(String toast) {
        OnomeTempHumUnavailableNotification();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showSecurDudeAlertNotification(String toast) {
        OnomeSecurDudeAlertNotification();
    }
}
```

The JavaScript File triggers the notification when a certain file is not available on the remote server.

```
function showDHT11Alert() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://serveraddress/OnomeWeb/resources/data/tmp/onomeDHT11On',
    success: function () {
        $('#onomenotif_DHT11Unavailable').hide();
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#onomenotif_DHT11Unavailable').show();
        showDHT11Toast();
    },
});
}

function showDHT11Toast(toast) {
        Android.showTempHumUnavailableNotification(toast);
}
```

The notification provider works perfecly, even if the app is in background, but obviously if I close the app from the recent apps screen, the notification provider stops working. Now I'd like to make this JavaScript Interface working in a background service, even if the app is closed from the recent apps.

The background service should be the best solution to my problem, but how can I interface this with the main WebView? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> The background service should be the best solution to my problem, but
>   how can I interface this with the main WebView? Is this possible?

Unfortunately its not possible. The JavaScriptInterface is injected by your app by calling

`OnomeWebContainer.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");`

And its only available to your WebView. Other WebViews won't inject it and as a result won't be able to trigger your `showTempHumUnavailableNotification`

Comment: @IvanS. Unfortunately no workaround available. It will only work if your app is in foreground and loads the WebView within your app.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought I may create a Service that interrogates the remote server for file availability (independent from the WebView), and according to this, it triggers the notification. This might be a workaround, because it's independent from the WebView. Obviously, this has to be executed in a kind of loop. Is this possible instead of using JavaScript Interface?

Comment: `I thought I may create a Service that interrogates the remote server for file availability` what do you mean?

Comment: For example, a Service that works in background with similar logic: 1) Check file at "http://address/target.file"; 2) If file exists; 2.1) Do nothing; 3) Else if file doesn't exist; 3.1) Trigger notification. And the service always has to check for file.

Comment: @IvanS. You don't have to loop continuously for this requirement. Just implement FileObserver. Some tutorial is available [here](http://www.roman10.net/2011/08/06/android-fileobserverthe-underlying-inotify-mechanism-and-an-example/)

Comment: Ok, I will give a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: @IvanS. let me know if it was useful

Comment: Hey Sagar, thanks for your interest about this. I found another way, that consists of creating a Service with AsyncTasks containing needed instructions to get a connection with the remote server and check if the file is available. Then it's possible to schedule and repeat them with a timer. Now the system must keep the service in background even if user closes the app from recents. A good way is to set the service as STICKY into onStartCommand, but there are two problems. First of all, I just found out that Android Oreo automatically stops the service, and...

Comment: I read somewhere the only way is to trigger a notification with high priority when the service is going to be reloaded by system, but I'm not sure about this. While on Nougat and earlier the "return Service.START_STICKY" works, but when I try to reopen the app from the app drawer, it crashes, so I have to reopen it again. Do you have any suggestions about these two issues?